# How to delete many to many DB in realm

Tags: android, realm

This is I tried

```
public class AppInfo extends RealmObject {
    public String packageName;

    public RealmList<CategoryInfo> categoryList;
}

public class CategoryInfo extends RealmObject { 
    public String categoryName;
}
```

This is my DB Table.

I wanna delete categoryName.

```
 AppInfo result = realm.where(AppInfo.class).equalTo("packageName",info.getPackageName()).findFirst();

result.categoryList.remove(category);
```

but the code can't delete categoryName.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
result.categoryList.remove(category);
```

You should do

```
result.categoryList.where().equalTo("categoryName", category).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
```

---

With Realm 3.4.0, you can also do

```
public class AppInfo extends RealmObject {
    public String packageName;

    public RealmList<CategoryInfo> categoryList;
}

public class CategoryInfo extends RealmObject { 
    public String categoryName;

    @LinkingObjects("categoryList")
    public final RealmResults<AppInfo> appInfos = null;
}
```

and

```
realm.where(CategoryInfo.class)
         .equalTo("appInfos.packageName", packageName)
         .equalTo("categoryName", category)
         .findAll()
         .deleteFromRealm();
```